# jquery: buggy cookie script? not always working?

Tags: jquery, cookies

hey guys,
something is kind of wrong with my script. i'm having a div #searchbox and a div #searchboxtrigger.

Fairly simpel: the #searchbox is hidden with display:none. if the #searchboxtrigger is clicked i'm slidingDown the #searchbox AND I'M SAVING A COOKIE. If i click the #searchboxtrigger again the #searchbox is slidingUp again and the cookie is set to null.

therefore i'm using the jquery cookie plugin.

onload i check if the cookie is set because if it's set the #searchbox should be visible when the page loads. if the #searchbox slidesUp again and the cookie is set to null, i don't want it to be visible.

onload:

```
    if($.cookie('search_visible') == 'true'){
        $('#searchbox').show();
        console.debug('is visible');
    }else{ 
        $('#searchbox').hide();
        console.debug('is hidden');
    }
```

onclick:

```
$('#searchboxtrigger').click( function() {
    if($.cookie('search_visible') == 'true') {
        $('#searchbox').slideUp('fast');
        $.cookie('search_visible', null);
        console.debug('is hidden');
    } else {
        $('#searchbox').slideDown('fast');
        $.cookie('search_visible', 'true');
        console.debug('is visible');
    } 
});
```

can you guys see anything weird? sometimes the #searchboxtrigger just doesn't respond and the console fires "is hidden" a dozen times till i reload.
is there anything i forgot to think of?

Comment: Looks good to me. Just to make sure, when you say onload, do you mean the onload event or the jquery ready?

Comment: since my searchbox is in my header and my header is set to display non when the page loads, i'm calling the first code section above when the header is displayed. it just seems that sometimes the cookie works, sometimes it doesn't. i just want it to work reliably. if it's clicked and the page reloads the #searchbox should always be visible, if not the #searchbox should be hidden on reload. something must be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the cookie to get the initial status, and write it when the status changes. Do not use it for the internal state, you keep a JavaScript var for that.

I'd also suggest making searchboxtrigger an `<a>` instead of a `<div>`, and precalculating jQuery DOM elements you are reusing.

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var searchVisible = $.cookie('search_visible') == 'true';
    var searchBox = $('#searchbox');

    if (searchVisible) {
        searchBox.show();
    } else { 
        searchBox.hide();
    }

    searchBox.click(function() {
        if (searchVisible) {
            searchBox.slideUp('fast');
            $.cookie('search_visible', null);
            searchVisible = false;
        } else {
            searchBox.slideDown('fast');
            $.cookie('search_visible', 'true');
            searchVisible = true;
        } 
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: thank you. however it seems like there is a different kind of problem. somehow when i test my script and your script it seems to work fine on my local mamp / xampp setup. However as soon as i transfer it to the real server. it seems like the cookie doesn't get saved. any idea why that could happen? the website is based on wordpress.

Comment: it's just like random. The cookie is set to true and to null correctly. I can tell when i'm looking in my console. However even if the cookie is set to true and i reload suddenly on reload the cookie is null. Sometimes when the cookie is null and i reload the cookie is true for some reason.